# Calling and passing to a method from class

Tags: c#, winforms, class, methods

I've got a main Form (called `Form1`), in which I've got a label (called `lbl1`).

Besides that I also have a method which looks like this:

```
public void SetLabelText(string lblText)
{
   lbl1.Text = lblText;
}
```

Now I want to call that method from a class (in my case it is called MyInput)

I've tried to call the method by

```
Form1 F1 = new Form1();
F1.SetLabelText="This is an example";
```

or by (not using the method I created)

```
Label L1 = new Form1().lbl1;
L1.Text = "This is an example";
```

However, in both cases, a second `Form1` opens and causes various problems with the rest of my program. The label itself has as modifiers public.

How can I achieve changing the label.text from within MyInput class?

Edit:
First of all, I want to thank you for your help. But the suggested solutions did not have the desired effect.

I think I will have to show you more of my code to solve this problem:

Form1:

```
namespace Project2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            .
            .
            .

            myInput.Check();
            
            public void SetLableText(string lblText)
            {
                lbl1.Text = lblText;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my class:

```
namespace Project2
{
    class MyInput
    {

        public static void Check()
        {
            CODE FOR CHECKING STATUS OF DEVICE

            if(status == 0)
            {
                //At this point lbl1.Text should be changed
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Why not just return a string with that text back to the form and change it there or pass your form into the new class

Comment: In both cases you are calling `new Form1()`, which makes a *new* form.  If you want MyInput to call a method on your already existing Form1, you need to pass a Form1 reference to MyInput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another suggestion:
Here is your method from your Form:

```
public void SetLabelText(string text)
{
    lbl1.Text = text;
}
```

in this class, you have your desired method which takes a `Form1` as a parameter
This will **only** work if `MyInput` and `Form1` are in the same namespace or if you add the appropriate reference!

```
class MyInput
{
   public static void Check(Form1 form)
   {
       // do what ever job you have to do
       form.SetLabelText("JobResultHere");
   }
}
```

**EDIT:**

now it depends strongly on where the call of this function happens:

```
MyInput.check(...
```

if the call is in the class of the Form with the label that needs to be changed, then you would call it like this

```
MyInput.check(this);
```

`this` represents the current instance of the class where the call happens.

if you would call it from somewhere else, make sure that the `Form1` instance is at hand.

**Don't** use `new` if you don't intend to create a new instance of the `Form1`

[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx) is the documentation on how to use `new` and what effects it will have on the program flow. Hope this can help.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However when i do it like this the VS says that he doesn't know `this` in `myinput.methodToCallMethodFromForm(this)`

Comment: @SUM from where to you want to call this method? Is your Form present there?

Comment: @SUM it seems a little twisted :) I guess you want to call the `MyInput` method somewhere outside the `Form1` may be in a third class?

Comment: I've added additional code to explain it in more detail. I don't know if you have seen it. However the call is embedded in a method which checks status of a device and should change the label if the device is operational.

Comment: @SUM ok now we are coming closer. One piece still missing! Where is the line of code which says: `MyInput.check()` ? is it in the file Form1.cs ?

Comment: The line `MyInput.check()` is in `Form1.cs` Sorry to cause confusion I'm still learning :(

Comment: I edited my answer to adapt to you edit. Please change your `Check` method and try again with `MyInput.check(this);`

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you very much. I would give you more than one thumbs-up if it be possible :)

Comment: you are very welcome. Wish you fun learning this nice language. :)

Answer (score 0):

By calling `Form F1 = new Form1()` you are creating a new instance of the form, which is why you're seeing a second window.

You need to store a reference to the form somewhere when it's first created. Then you need to call `SetLabelText()` on that instance.

For example

```
// Program.cs
public static Form1 _form;
// sample main method
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    _form = new Form1();
    Application.Run(_form);
}
```

Then you can call it as `Program._form.SetLabelText("Whatever the string is.");`

Answer (score -1):

First of all you are creating a new instance of Form1 every time you use new keyword that changes another form somewhere afterwards.

A sample code for what you need can be done like

```
class MyInput
{
    private Form1 form;

    public MyInput(Form1 form1)
    {
        this.form = form1;
        setFormText("test");
    }

    private void setFormText(string text)
    {
        form.label1.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Like this you can do it like when in your form1

```
var myinput = new MyInput(this);
```

and Form1 be used in MyInput class.
With the same method you can pass instances of forms to another forms via constructor.

However if you are trying to do what you have done in your code sample, you would probably need to do more research on what Reference and what Instance is.

Comment: The problem here is that if you instantiate the form within `MyInput` and it's the main form for the application, the `Main()` method will have to create program wide instance of `MyInput`.

Comment: The label is private anyways in most cases. You can't touch it here.

Comment: @Adam OP wrote "The label itself has as modifiers public." so i answered like that

Comment: @BarryO'Kane it is just a sample for him to how to use instances properly. I do think that code is not really good also.

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't read close enough :-)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried this but it couldn't solve my problem. I've added some more code in order to explain the issue in more detail. Maybe that can lead me to an answer.